# Ubuntu 20.04.3 (not waking up after suspend) and (can not shutdown or restart)

Tags: suspend, shutdown

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3
Laptop: Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5
CPU & GPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700U (8 core, 16 thread) with Radeon Graphics

When I close my laptop's lid or manually suspend I can not get the screen to turn on without holding the power button and completely restarting the computer.

I can also not restart or power off the computer without holding down the power button. The screen turns black and hangs on a flickering "_".

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, or an intentional reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Comment: How much RAM and swap do you have?

Comment: I have 16gb of RAM

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem, try going into grub menu and switching to the "older" linux kernel (most probably it'll be 5.11.0-27-generic). switching to 5.11.0-27-generic kernel solved it for my hp-15-ba021ax(AMD) running ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: If I boot from 5.8.0-49 then the power off and restart works but suspend still doesn't work. I guess I'll just have to live with it for now it isn't that big of an issue, hopefully it gets fixed in the new LTS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Downgrading from 5.13 to 5.11 kernel also helped me on my lenovo ideapad 5 with AMD cpu

Answer (score 0):

I have a [Dell inspiron 2 in 1 running on ryzen 7 5825u](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/dell-inspiron-2-in-1-14-fhd-touch-laptop-amd-ryzen-7-16gb-memory-512gb-ssd-pebble-green/6503233.p?skuId=6503233&ref=212&loc=1&extStoreId=498&ref=212&loc=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAmaibBhCAARIsAKUlaKTlMZfo0vLfu6CRzBhDZIa56_MuFDTY7_EGBn7HumT6N4fxsTNWc5gaAkVtEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). The Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS's kernel 5.15 caused the suspend by closing the lid to not wake. I had to basically long press the power button to shut it and pressed it again to boot it. It was annoying. I did not change GRUB or xorg display but to [upgrade](https://linuxhint.com/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/) to Kernel 6.0.0 to solve the problem. I notice that kernel 6.0.7 also solves the suspend problem but the wifi would not be able to egress to the Internet on Chrome. It could curl [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) but somehow Chrome,Firefox couldn't reach Google. So I landed on Kernel 6.0.0 and tried suspend 3 times. So far each time I can just press any a-z key to wake it.